# Name of topology analogous to Zariski topology for an arbitrary model of a first-order theory

Tags: general-topology, model-theory, zariski-topology

In the [Zariski topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zariski_topology#Affine_varieties), a set of points in $A^n$, $w$, is closed by definition when there exists a set of polynomials in $n$ variables, $S$, such that the following holds.

$$ \forall u \in A^n \mathop. \bigg( u \in w \iff (\forall f \in S \mathop. f(u) = 0) \bigg) $$

By squinting, we can come up with a topology with a similar definition that works for an arbitrary model of a first-order theory and convince ourselves that it's really a topology.

**I'm wondering what this topology's name is (if it has one) and whether it is at all useful for classifying models in some way.**

Let $L$ be a language with constant, function, and relation symbols.

Let $\theta$ be a set of $L$-sentences.

Let $M$ be our model, $M \models \theta$.

Let $V$ be a set of well-formed formulas where each well-formed formula has exactly one free variable $x$. We can assume that the free variable is named $x$ without losing any generality.

We define $w$ to be a closed set when the following holds:

$$ \forall u \in M_D \mathop. \bigg( u \in w \iff (\forall v \in V \mathop. v[x:=u] \;\;\text{is true in $M$}) \bigg) $$

We can show that this thing is really a topology.

Let $F$ be a family of sets of wff's. The subset of $M_D$ associated with $\cup F$ is closed, therefore the closed sets of our topology are closed under arbitrary intersection.

To show closure under finite union, it suffices to show closure under binary unions.

Suppose we have two sets of wffs with one free variable $A$ and $B$. Further suppose that in each wff in $A$ and each wff in $B$ the free variable is named $x$.

Define $C$ as follows:

$$ C \stackrel{\text{def}}{=\!=} \{ a \lor b \mathop. a \in A \land b \in B \} $$

In other words, we take every pair of wffs where the left formula comes form $A$ and the right formula comes from $B$ and join them together with a $\lor$.

The empty set is given by the formula $\exists x \mathop. x \neq x$.

The whole domain of the model is given by the formula $\exists x \mathop. x = x$.

Comment: I'm sorry. I meant to use $\cup F$. You can get the intersection of an arbitrary family of sets of wffs by just imposing all the conditions simultaneously ... which corresponds to the union.

Comment: More snappily, this is **the topology generated by the definable sets** (keep in mind that the negation of a formula is again a formula!). I've heard this called "the logic topology," but I can't immediately find a written reference for that.

Comment: @NoahSchweber: The logic topology is mostly about quotients of invariant sets by bounded invariant equivalence relations (over a small parameter set). To be fair, this does technically apply, since a small model is invariant over itself, but it'd be a rather odd thing to do, and the topology would be simply discrete (as it would be for any quotient of a small set).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by $M_D$. If you mean the underlying set of $M$ and you consider all formulas with parameters in $M$, then this is simply the discrete topology.

I believe the topology you are trying to describe is simply the restriction of the usual Stone topology in the type space $S_x(A)$ (for a fixed $A\subseteq M$, perhaps simply $A=\emptyset$) to the subspace of types of elements of $M$.

I don't think it has any widely-used name. If I would refer to it, I would just describe it as I did in the preceding paragaph. If I had to name it, I would just (abusively) call it the Stone topology (in $M$ over $A$). The Stone topology on the space of types is definitely useful in model theory, since it allows us to talk about definable phenomena in essentially purely topological terms. This particular restriction --- I'm not so sure about.

---

**Edit**: In hindsight, this topology will certainly not reproduce the Zariski topology in the case of algebraically closed fields. To do that, you need to consider some refinements: instead of *all* formulas, you can only consider formulas of particular form, e.g. quantifier-free positive formulas (formulas with no quantifiers nor negations). (Note: thanks to Alex Kruckman to pointing out an erreneous remark about pp-formulas being equivalent to positive quantifier-free formulas.)

Then the resulting topology on $M$ is not discrete. Still, even in this case, I think it would be more natural to consider the topology on the space of complete (qf positive) types. I *think* this is similar to how in algebraic geometry an affine scheme is not completely captured by its underlying Zariski topological space. (Although as noted by Alex in the comments, the closer analogy is the topology on the spectrum of the coordinate ring of an affine variety.)

Comment: $M_D$ is meant to be the domain of the model $M$, yes. I don't understand why this construction would always give you the discrete topology, however. In $\mathbb{R}$ as an ordered field, I don't think it's the case that all the singleton sets are open.

Comment: @GregoryNisbet: Formulas of the form $x\neq c$ show that singletons are open. Now that I think of it, if you really wanted something analogous to the Zariski topology, you should conisder only *positive* formulas (without negations), or some subset, such as quantifier-free positive formulas of pp-formulas (formulas of the form $\exists x \varphi(x,y)$ for a q-free $\varphi$). Each of these restrictions gives rise to its own complete type spaces, and the restrictions of these topologies to $M$ need not be trivial.

Comment: "$\exists$ quantifier can be eliminated without adding negations." Unfortunately, this is not true: $\exists y (xy = 1)$ defines $M\setminus \{0\}$, which is not defined by any positive quantifier-free formula. To put it another way, the projection of a Zariski-closed set is always constructable, but may not be Zariski-closed.

Comment: Regarding schemes: The distinction between considering the Stone topology on a particular model vs on the type space is more analogous to the move, for an affine variety $V$, from considering the Zariski topology on the $K$-points of $V$ for a particular field $K$ to the Zariski topology on the prime spectrum of the coordinate ring of $V$. This introduces generic points, which are in analogy to the non-realized types in the type space. The difference between a scheme and its underlying topological space involves the structure sheaf, which doesn't have a clear analogue in model theory.

Comment: @AlexKruckman: You're right about the projections of algebraic sets. I don't know why I thought that was true. Fixed that. Regarding schemes: I did not have any concrete correspondence in mind, I just meant that there is more structure around than the topology on the underlying space can see, although I agree that the spectrum is more analogous (being a topological space, to begin with). Anyway, I'm not sure whether I've seen anyone actually do that, but I don't see why wouldn't you be able to define a "sheaf" (or even an actual sheaf, if you have a definable topology) of definable functions.

Comment: Sure, you can consider sheaves of definable functions (and people do this in some contexts, e.g. in o-minimality), but they don't seem to have the same foundational importance as the structure sheaf in scheme theory. I guess what I'm saying is that I'm not aware of a satisfying model-theoretic generalization of the notion of a scheme.